# LFTP: save username/password for specific server?

Tags: configuration, ftp, passwords, lftp

Can I save a username/password pair for an ftp server in some local configuration file, so that `lftp` will find them automatically when connecting to that server?

Background: I have script which will be used by multiple users, with different username/password pairs, to sync some generated content from a repository to an ftp server.  It would be nice not to have to enter our usernames/passwords by hand each time.  Since ftp passwords are sent in cleartext, we are all using low-value passwords for this, so storing the passwords in cleartext in a local config file is acceptable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use **~/.netrc** file or lftp bookmarks.

Add something like this to **~/.netrc**:

```
machine your.server.example.com login your_login password your_password
```

Then lftp will pick the password when opening *ftp://your_login@your.server.example.com*, and it will use *your_login* automatically when opening *"your.server.example.com"* **without the URL syntax**.

When using bookmarks, do *"set bmk:save-passwords true"* (default is false), then save the current session to bookmarks under a name, then *"open bookmark_name"* will use the login/password pair. The bookmarks file is plain text, so you can even add the URL with login/password by any text editor. To use a common bookmarks for all users set **LFTP_HOME** environment variable to a common directory.

Answer (score 4):

Just some more details about lftp bookmarks:

First add line set `bmk:save-passwords yes` to the main lftp config file `/etc/lftp.conf`.

Now every user can add his own bookmark:

```
lftp -c "bookmark add SiteName ftp://user:password@sitename.com/path"
```

When using lftp in a script just use:

```
lftp -c "open SiteName && lcd MyLocalDir && mput ./*"
```